# accessing DOM elements by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Say I have the following DOM element in my piece of code:

```
<div id="test">
    <div id="t2">
       Hi I am
       <b>Gopi</b>
       and am 20 years old.
       <p id="div2">
         <button onclick="alert('lol')">Check</button>
       </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Suppose I wanted to traverse through the contents of div#t2.

`$("#t2").children()` gives me the `<b>` and `<p>` tags.

*So **how** should I access it to get the values as an array containing "`Hi I am`", "`<b>....</b>`", "`and am 20 years old.`", "`<p>.....</p>`* **??**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the native DOM [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node):

```
$('#t2')[0].childNodes
```

Gives you the array you want.

You'll probably want to trim the entries before using them using [$.trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) too since the actual text node contains all the whitespace in your HTML.

Comment: `$.trim($("#t2")[0].childNodes[0])` returns "[object Text]", not the trimmed html. any solution other than manually removing whitespaces from the beginning and end?

Comment: @gopi1410 Text nodes aren't strings themselves but they contain a string in `nodeValue`. Try this: `$.trim($("#t2")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue)`

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. is there any way to get the whole string for HTML nodes? , `innerHTML` omits the Node name and gives it's `inner html`. OP's need the nodeName too.

Comment: @Joy To get outerHTML you can add the current element to a new div and then get its innerHTML. It's a bit hacky, but it works: `$('<div>').appendChild($("#t2")[0].childNodes[1]).html()`

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. thanks for this I was looking for an easier way, than a direct check.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. , thanks again, used your idea in my answer, hope you wont  mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can get that using [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method

```
var arr = $("#t2").contents().get();
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/LNW4V/1/)

If you check the fiddle you will find that `.contents()` is returning an array consisting of

`text` and `html` elements like

```
 [text1,html1,text2,html2,text3]

 //Where
 text1 == Hi I am
 html1 == <b>Gopi</b>
 text2 == and am 20 years old. 
 html2 == <p id="div2"><button onclick="alert('lol')">Check</button></p>
```

That perfectly makes sense, but where is the last `text3` coming from.

There is another text nodes at the end of `<p>` tag

```
 <p id="div2">....</p> <-- Here, newline is 
                           another text node(the last one)
```

So if you use `.contents` keep that in mind.

To get trimmed data use $.map like

```
var arr = $("#t2").contents().map(function(){
 if (this.nodeType == 3)
     return $.trim(this.nodeValue) || null; 
                                     // this null to omit last textnode
 else
     return $('<div />').append(this).html();

 });
```

Comment: `.children()` won't select text nodes.

Comment: yeah, thanks.. didn't know about `contents()`. It would be quite easy now.

Comment: @Joy thanks, but how do I trim the data? $.trim($("#t2").contents()[0]) gives "[object Text]" not the text value inside it

Comment: @Joy now you removed copied element and updated, which is also not something better at all, previous was more better

Comment: @thecodeparadox, I leant that thing from your answer and commented there and added in my answer, I asked PaulP.R.O. at the same time for a way and he gave one, found that better and added that. I mean no offense and I am  a newbie, not expert like you guys. I can remove the answer if you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12124/discussion-between-joy-and-thecodeparadox)

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = [];

$("#t2").contents().map(function(index, el) {
    console.log(el);
    if(el.nodeType == 3) {
        result.push($.trim( $(el).text() ));
    } else {
        if(el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'b') {
          result.push('<b>' + el.innerHTML + '</b>');
        } else if(el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'p') {
          result.push('<p>' + el.innerHTML + '</p>');            
        }
   }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/LNW4V/4/)**

Comment: @gopi1410 check my answer and demo. I think you will get what you want

Comment: there is `<p>` nodes too, have to add check for that too. Thanks for the idea. I was searching for a way to doing this.

Comment: @thecodeparadox but in this case, I have to check manually for all the tags? The above example just had b & p tags, so was easy..